# How to pass id from Html::link to controller

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, laravelcollective

I have a link

```
 {{ Html::link('/Edit/$user->s_no', 'Edit', array('id' => $user->s_no,'class' =>'btn btn-info'), true)}}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/Edit/{id}',['as'=>'EditUser','uses'=>'RegistrationController@Edit']);
```

**controller**

```
public function Edit($id)
    {
       echo $id;
    }
```

But when i echo $id it always shows $user->s_no(static) as value.I want to get id as 1,2,3 etc.What is wrong with me?I don't know i am doing right way or not.Please help me?

Comment: is that working for you ..?

Comment: @Anurag_Systematix -I get id as $user->s_no but not get 1 2 3 always echo $user->s_no as static..

Comment: @Anurag_Systematix-Any problem with controller?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 {{ Html::link('/Edit/id', 'Edit', array('id' => 1,'class' =>'btn btn-info'), true)}}
```

or

```
 {{ Html::link('/Edit/$user->s_no', 'Edit', array('id' => 1,'class' =>'btn btn-info'), true)}}
```

and if you setting id dynamically then you should get that value in variable first and then concatenate it with id like:

```
 {{ Html::link('/Edit/id', 'Edit', array('id' => "your variable" ,'class' =>'btn btn-info'), true)}}
```

Comment: if i use {{ Html::link('/Edit/id', 'Edit', array('id' => 1,'class' =>'btn btn-info'), true)}}  i get id as simply id means i dint get 1,2,3

Comment: try this  {{ Html::link('/Edit/id=1', 'Edit', array('id' => 1,'class' =>'btn btn-info'), true)}}

Comment: this is working fine..but instead of id=1 i want to set my variable here but how?

Comment: Now you can concatenate you variable instead of 1 in above code like :{{ Html::link('/Edit/id='+$user->s_no, 'Edit', array('id' => 1,'class' =>'btn btn-info'), true)}}

Comment: i dont know i am beginner in laravel.Please help me

Comment: @Anurag_Systematix- Thanks a lot.it's working but its didint show function edit in url now browser url seems https://localhost/laravel_demo/public/1 but i need https://localhost/laravel_demo/public/edit/1

Comment: @Shanu k k please mark solution as answer so that it can help other

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131509/discussion-between-shanu-k-k-and-anurag-systematix).

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link for more detail link [enter link description here](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/191/generating-a-html-link-to-a-controller-action)

If the controller action method takes arguments, you can specify them in the third parameter, as a simple array.

```
{{ HTML::linkAction('ItemController@show', 'Show Item #3', array(3)) }}
```

The HTML would look like below (depending on your routes).

```
<a href="http://your.url/items/3">Show Item #3</a>
```

[image]